# Change port on spring boot

Tags: selenium, spring-boot

> I tried to change the port to use in spring boot by writing following code

```
package steinKo.ATM;

import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer;
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class CustomisationServlet implements EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer {

    @Override
    public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {
         container.setPort(9000);
        
    }

}
```

> But the application did not change port
> jul 13, 2017 7:20:18 PM
> org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverServer start INFO: Server
> started on port 38002 jul 13, 2017 7:20:18 PM
> org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor start INFO:
> Launching Safari
>
> What must I do to get this code active?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to set up a server port in Spring Boot.

1) is to set it in `application.properties` located in `src/main/resources` : `server.port=8888`

2) in application.yaml:

`server:
    port: 8888`

3) Dynamically as a system property: `System.setProperty("server.port", 80);`

4) While bootstraping aplication for example `-Dserver.port=8888`

5) For test purposes (as I see you added tag selenium I guess you want to run some tests on top of this app) you need to add annotations to your test class:

`@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
@TestPropertySource(properties = "server.port=8888")`

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the server port by using the `application.properties` file located at `src/main/resources`

```
server.port=9000
```